# Why does my Spark only use two computers in the cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I'm using Spark 1.3.1 on StandAlone mode in my cluster which has 7 machines. 2 of the machines are powerful and have 64 cores and 1024 GB memory, while the others have 40 cores and 256 GB memory. One of the powerful machines is set to be the master, and others are set to be the slaves. Each of the slave machine runs 4 workers.

When I'm running my driver program on one of the powerful machines, I see that it takes the cores only from the two powerful machines. Below is a part of the web UI of my spark master.

[image: The web UI]

My configuration of this Spark driver program is as follows:

```
spark.scheduling.mode=FAIR
spark.default.parallelism=32
spark.cores.max=512
spark.executor.memory=256g
spark.logConf=true
```

Why spark does this? Is this a good thing or a bad thing? Thanks!

Comment: Your configuration specifies that your executors need 256GB memory. I'm thinking that you need to lower this, since 256GB is all memory on the slaves and there are other processes running on the workers that need memory as well. As a general rule, you should only assign ~75% of available memory.

Comment: Just as you said, Spark distributes the cores among all the machines after I lowered the memory to 200GB. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider **lowering your executors memory** from the 256GB that you have defined.

For the future, take in consideration assigning around 75% of available memory.